# HSQLDB and Stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, hsqldb

There is probably a good document out there that explains how to create a stored proc in HSQLDB. Here's where I'm getting stuck :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addone(ivar int)
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE result CURSOR FOR SELECT ivar+1;
OPEN result;    
END
```

However is simply get ERROR back - no details - any ideas anyone ?

Comment: The manual has several examples: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_routines

Comment: Do not use RESULT as a name. To use a SELECT like yours, you should use the MySQL or PostgreSQL compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

Below, is a sample HSQL Procedure, from a HSQL test file you downloaded with hsqldb.zip file ( in directory testrun\hsqldb\TestSelfStoredProcedure.txt ) at line 441.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_test(INOUT val INT) READS SQL DATA
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  BEGIN ATOMIC
   declare curs cursor for select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name='LOB_IDS' and table_schema='SYSTEM_LOBS';
   select count(*) into val from information_schema.columns where table_name='LOB_IDS' and table_schema='SYSTEM_LOBS';
   open curs;
  END
```

---

Please note that your Select statement, is NOT a complete Select statement, at least as you have posted it,

Sliderule

Comment: Trying to use the above in SquirrelSQL I get the error CREATE Error: unexpected end of statement:  required: ; : line: 4
SQLState:  42590
ErrorCode: -5590
Error occured in:
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_test(INOUT val INT) READS SQL DATA
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  BEGIN ATOMIC
   declare curs cursor for select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name='LOB_IDS' and table_schema='SYSTEM_LOBS'

Comment: I used SqlTool ( sqltool.jar ) to execute the CREATE PROCEDURE statement, and, it worked perfectly. SqlTool is included in your download of the HSQL database in file hsqldb.zip . Additionally, I was able to accomplish the task using both, Database Manager, and, Database Manager Swing . . . tools available from HSQL database.

Comment: Just one additional comment or thought . . . the program . . .SQL Workbench . . . that can be downloaded from http://www.sql-workbench.net/  and   it explicitly addresses ( solves ) the issue, please read this web page:  http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#error-create-procedure